# AFNetworking 1.3.1 image download responseObject is nil

Tags: ios, afnetworking

After I updated the version of AFNetworking in my project to 1.3.1 from 1.3.0, the download of images stopped working.

I tried using *setImageWithUrl:placeholderImage*: and *setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure*: but on both cases the responseObject returned is nil.

It works ok if I go back to 1.3.0

The other AFNetworking operations I'm doing works well on both version, the problems seems to be just with the image download.

I use Cocoapods.

Comment: I would probably file an issue on the AFNetworking github page. You are likely to get a better answer from one of the contributors. It will also notify them if there is really a problem with that.

Comment: Agree with Bill.  I've found them to be very responsive.

Comment: I also feel like I read some discussion they were having about whether or not the UIImage category methods really belonged in AFNetworking.  They may be removing them.  If you just do a normal download, get the NSData and set the image yourself, does it work?

Comment: yes, it works using dataWithContentsOfURL: + imageWithData:

Comment: Gonna go ahead and ask in the github page, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking 1.3.1 introduced an update to the way images are loaded, inflating them asynchronously, for better UI responsiveness. There may be some bugs to work out—and if you think you've found one, please report it on AFNetworking's GitHub Issues.

In the meantime, you can set the [`automaticallyInflatesResponseImage`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFImageRequestOperation.html#//api/name/automaticallyInflatesResponseImage) property to `NO` on `AFImageRequestOperation` to return to the previous behavior.

Comment: Setting automaticallyInflatesResponseImage to NO worked, but it turned out I'm not saving my images properly in my webserver. The ios App is getting jpeg images with Content-Type: image/png.
In AFInflatedImageFromResponseWithDataAtScale method I used CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider for image/png content type and it worked. Thanks a lot for the answer